# A8VMX.ROM can't be found

Tags: motherboard

I was using my computer and then my monitor went black and displayed the following lines :

A8VMX.ROM can't be found
looking for cd-rom
cd-rom found
A8VMX.ROM can't be found on cd-rom
looking for floppy
...

**And my motherboard model is A8VMX.**

So what does it mean ? Motherboard is dead ? Or a simple reinstall of windows XP should do the trick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does sound like your bios is damaged and that your motherboard is trying to auto-repair. This is a feature on many of Asus motherboards, here's the description from their website.

> CrashFree BIOS 2 
>   Whenever BIOS gets corrupted, ASUS CrashFree BIOS 2 allows users to reboot the computer and perform an smart auto-recovery procedure through the motherboard support CD.

Try inserting your motherboard CD and reboot, it should auto-repair. If it doesn't your motherboard may very well be broken.